# How do I set up PHPUnit locally on a Windows laptop?

Tags: php, terminal, phpunit

I have no software related to PHP on my laptop. I know how to code in PHP and have previously used Subversion through Eclipse which connects to a web server but unfortunately I'm struggling to find anything that tells you how to create a PHP setup on a local machine including PHPUnit so that I can practice test driven development.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an eminently [searchable question](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=install+php+on+windows), plenty of results there! Get PHP and a web server installed first, worry about PHPUnit afterwards. That's quite easy as well - I think it is run via PEAR. Consider an all-in-one solution, search for keywords "WAMP" or "XAMPP".

Comment: What os? This works well for basic development in windows http://www.zachsaw.com/?pg=quickphp_php_tester_debugger

Comment: Luke makes a good point. Although this question isn't ideal for here (as it duplicates thousands readily available on the web) it is always good to be precise about what you have. Windows XP, 7, 8 etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably using [**XAMPP**](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), as is already installs a PEAR environment.

Install XAMPP first, then to install PHPUnit click the "Shell" button in the XAMPP control panel and enter the following commands:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
pear channel-discover components.ez.no

pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Comment: The install documents on PHPUnit's base site cover this as well as some of the optional components.  The basic install above works correctly, but checking http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/installation.html will cover the installation process as well.

Comment: @StevenScott upvote from me for the link to the install guide; However it will of course not cover the XAMPP part ;)